# Unexpected error for long-duration chat events

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I wanted to host a chatroom event that would last 4320 minutes, but instead of successful event creation, or even a disappointing notice that my event's duration was much too long, all that I have been given is a kitty working on a computer.

---

I also tried with 2160 minutes and 1440 minutes. This was on chat.stackexchange.com - I wanted to add the event to the GDSE GameJam room, the events title was GDSE GameJam 1.

Comment: All hail our Kitty Overlords!

Comment: So you've been given cats working on a computer? Then what's the problem?

Comment: Some of us have to sleep, y'know.

Comment: On which chat did this happen?

Comment: @Sklivvz Stackexchange, I was trying to add a new event in a room linked to gamedev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem trying to schedule long chat events, but anything over 1440 minutes will be changed back to 1440.

So, that's not the problem you were having. By looking at the code and the exception generated I figured there was an unreported parsing error in the date you used. I fixed that.

The fix will be deployed in the next build.